# Invalid property name on padding

Tags: html, css, sass

I have different `padding` values based on `media queries`. But, upon inspect, those padding values are not being implemented and it's returned `invalid property values` and I'm unsure why?

[image]

My `scss`:

```css
.myAccount {
  padding: 140px 0 40px 0;
  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    padding: 180px ​0 100px 0;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
    padding: 200px ​0 130px 0;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
    padding: 220px 0 120px 0;
  }
}
```

On large screens (i.e. 1200px), the default padding (`140px 0 40px 0`) is being applied, as the media query isn't kicking in.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap and its `media-breakpoint-up` or did you write it yourself?

Comment: Whoever/whatever has written the media queries has forgotten to put the opening and closing curly brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was incredibly hard to debug, pure luck helped me. When I've pasted your code into codepen I've realised that you have a [zero-width space symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) right before zero in the first two padding declarations, check it out:

[image]

Removing those must resolve the issue

Comment: Ah, you're a legend! removing those worked. Unsure how they got there in the first place, but happy it's resolved :) thanks